# How to scroll down to 90% of your document or body's height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to scroll down to particularly 90% of my document or body's height, **not the screen height of the device**. I understand that this example below would scroll down to a certain element of my page or document.

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $("#emptydisplay").offset().top }, 500);
```

but that is not what I need. I need to scroll down automatically to 90% of whatever my HTML document's height might be. I tried something like this

```
 $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() * 0.90 });
```

but it's scrolling down all the way to the bottom.

How do I do this in jquery? Thanks...

Comment: use 90% of (bodyhieght-windowheight )

Comment: Can you setup a fiddle/jsbin? I see http://jsbin.com/mugopebora/edit?html,css,js,output it's working fine

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6z335yu7/

Comment: @mohamedrias I'm not sure why it's working on your fiddle but on my page it won't work work the way I would expect. But it's resolved now though. Thanks to all who help...Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scrollTop` means the top side of your window. `scrollTop: 100%` means `full height of the page - the height of the window`. If you want `90%`, you need this:

```
$('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() * 0.9 - $(window).height() }, 500);
```

Answer (score 2):

you should remove the window height from document height

```
$('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: ($(document).height() * 0.90)-$(window).height() });
```

Comment: open console in this page only and test it

Answer (score 1):

you should minus window's height

```
 $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() * 0.90 - $(window).height() });
```